# Return 0 Value with Count in Oracle From Single Table

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have this one table named `Vouchers`:

```
ID_ENTITY -> Unique Key
ID_VOUCHER 
VOUCHER_CODE
AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM
ID_VOUCHER_STATUS
DAT_EXPIRE_DATE
```

and i have a count query:

```
select count(*),AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM,ID_VOUCHER 
from CUS_VOUCHERS
where ID_VOUCHER_STATUS = 0 
and ID_VOUCHER = 1 
and trunc(DAT_EXPIRE_DATE) >= trunc(sysdate)
group by AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM,ID_VOUCHER;
```

result :

```
-----------------------------------------
COUNT | AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM |  ID_VOUCHER
1     |100000              |1
      |                    |
```

expected result:

```
----------------------------------------
COUNT | AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM  | ID_VOUCHER
1     | 100000              |1
0     |150000               |1
0     |200000               |1
```

actually i have many `AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM` with `ID_VOUCHER = 1` but the `ID_VOUCHER_STATUS != 0`.

how can i do it?

Comment: If you can post some sample data from your `vouchers` table then it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the filter on ID_VOUCHER_STATUS and use a `case` statement to count the items of interest

```
select count(case when ID_VOUCHER_STATUS = 0 then 1 end) as no_of_sts_0
       , AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM,ID_VOUCHER 
from CUS_VOUCHERS
where ID_VOUCHER = 1 
and trunc(DAT_EXPIRE_DATE) >= trunc(sysdate)
group by AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM,ID_VOUCHER;
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9c4b/1)

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE ID_VOUCHER_STATUS = 0 and ID_VOUCHER = 1` will exclude all `AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM` with `ID_VOUCHER_STATUS != 0`.

So you want to execute:

```
select count(*),AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM,ID_VOUCHER from CUS_VOUCHERS
where ID_VOUCHER = 1 and trunc(DAT_EXPIRE_DATE) >= trunc(sysdate)
group by AMNT_VOUCHER_DENOM,ID_VOUCHER;`
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question.